# Android Error: duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle

While using a project as a dependency I'm having trouble.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile project(':androidCommUnits')
    compile project(':share')
    compile project(':qrcodeLibrary')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
    compile project(':ultimaterecyclerview')

    compile files('libs/alipaysdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/alipaysecsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/alipayutdid.jar')
    compile files('libs/libammsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinyin4j-2.5.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/locSDK_6.11.jar')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'org.xutils:xutils:3.2.2'

    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile project(':easyloadingbtn-lib')

    compile(project(':OneSDK')) {
        exclude module: 'alipaySingle-20160223'
        exclude module: 'utdid4all-1.0.4'
    }

}
```

I get this Error：

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':youke:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/alipay/android/app/IAlixPay$Stub$a.class
```

This is one class I see duplicate

[image]
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need to add some more `exclude module: ...` statements to `compile(project(':OneSDK')) {` in order to exclude all the duplicates that are included elsewhere.

Comment: I did not make things right, how it does it!

Comment: exclude rules how to write？